# XSL-FO implementing pictures with a loop

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

My Problem is that I have an XML File with a valid structure and all of the pictures are placed in the following path.

```
<figure>
   <graphic url="Alexander.jpg" width="180px" height="281px" />
   <figDesc>Alexander</figDesc>
 </figure>
```

IN XSL the solution to add a loop and to place the pictures in the generated html file is clear. I use something like this

```
<figure>
<img src="{tei:figure/tei:graphic/@url}" 
width="{substring-before(tei:figure/tei:graphic/@width, 'px')}" 
alt="{tei:figure/tei:figDesc}" />     
</figure>
```

But in XSL FO I have only the possibility to add pictures like that. And i really don`t want to place them by hand.

```
<fo:block>
 <fo:external-graphic src="Alexander.jpg" />
</fo:block>
```

So can you please assist with a little help? Cheers Christian

Comment: Since you already know what an image in XSL-FO must look like and have valid TEI, what's the problem? How is generating HTML different from generating XSL-FO in this respect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute value templates work with any non-XSLT attribute (and with many XSLT-defined attributes).  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates.

So you can also do this in your XSLT:

```
<fo:block>
 <fo:external-graphic src="{tei:figure/tei:graphic/@url}" />
</fo:block>
```